# How to enable customer login to customer specific admin page

Tags: plugins

I would like to build a website that will let visitors register and get access to their own personal admin page.

So user #1 will input his login and password and get access to his admin page with his parameters. User #2 will see his own parameters, etc.

Is this possible using wordpress themes and plugins?
and if yes, which theme or plugin would you advise?

Answer (score 2):

I have done this in the past before, so I am reusing the code here. You will need to do some tweaking for it to mesh with your site. You will also need [Peter's Login Redirect](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/peters-login-redirect/) plugin.

*I did not explain the code because it would take too much time to work through all of it right now. If you have any trouble please add a comment and I will try my best to explain. I am also assuming you have WordPress knowledge.*

Create Custom Post Type for Client Area

```
//CLIENT AREA
add_action('init', 'create_client_area');
function create_client_area() {
    register_taxonomy( 'client_category', array(), array(
        'hierarchical' => true,
        'labels' => array(
            'name' => 'Clients',
            'singular_name' => 'Client'
        ),
        'show_ui' => true,
        'query_var' => true,
        'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'clientarea' )
    ));
    register_post_type( 'client', array(
        'labels' => array(
            'name' => 'Client Area',
            'singular_name' => 'Client Project'
        ),
        'supports' => array('title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'comments'),
        'public' => true,
        'hierarchical' => false,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'show_in_menu' => true,
        'capability_type' => 'post',
        'rewrite' => array(
            'slug' => 'clientarea/%client_category%',
            'with_front' => false
        ),
        'query_var' => true,
        //'has_archive' => 'work',
        'has_archive' => false,
        'taxonomies' => array( 'client_category' )
    ));
}
add_filter('post_type_link', 'client_area_permalink', 10, 4);
function client_area_permalink($post_link, $post, $leavename, $sample) {
    if ( false !== strpos( $post_link, '%client_category%' ) ) {
        $client_category = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'client_category' );
        if(!$client_category) { $client_category = array(); }

        $post_link = str_replace( '%client_category%', array_pop($client_category)->slug, $post_link );
    }
    return $post_link;
}
```

Create a Term for each User

```
// CLIENT ROLE
add_role( 'client', 'Client', array('read') );

// CREATE TERM ON REGISTER
add_action('user_register', 'create_client_category', 10, 3);
function create_client_category( $user_ID ) {
    $user = new WP_User( $user_ID );
    if( in_array('client', $user->roles) ) {
        $userdata = get_userdata($user_ID);
        if( !term_exists($userdata->user_nicename, 'client_category') ) {
            wp_insert_term( $userdata->user_login, 'client_category', array(
                'slug' => $userdata->user_nicename ));
        }
    }   
}
```

Add Credential Check in [Specialized Header](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_header)

```
function show_404() {
    global $wp_query;
    $wp_query->set_404();
    status_header( 404 );
    get_template_part( 404 ); exit();
}

if(is_page()) {
    if( current_user_can('client') ) {
        global $user_ID;
        $user = get_userdata( $user_ID );
        if(term_exists($user->user_nicename, 'client_category')) {
            wp_redirect( home_url('/clientarea/'.$user->user_nicename.'/') ); exit;
        } else { show_404(); }
    } elseif( !current_user_can('administrator') ) { show_404(); }
} elseif(is_tax()) {
    if( !current_user_can('administrator') && get_userdata($user_ID)->user_nicename != $wp_query->queried_object->slug) { // not admin and not user page
        show_404();
    }
} elseif(is_single()) {
    global $user_ID;
    $user = get_userdata( $user_ID );
    $terms = get_the_terms($post->id, 'client_category');
    foreach( $terms as $term ) {
        if($term->slug != $user->user_nicename) $deny = true;
    }
    if( !current_user_can('administrator') && $deny) {
        show_404();
    }
} else {
    // dont know what goes here...thinking.
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your input. Though I would rather use a ready-made solution.

Answer (score 0):

Found a wordpress plugin that seems to fit:

http://codecanyon.net/item/privatecontent-multilevel-content-plugin/1467885?WT.ac=search_item&WT.seg_1=search_item&WT.z_author=LCweb